# Flatlist scroll doesn't work after InitialScrollIndex

Tags: react-native, tvos, react-native-flatlist

I work on a horizontal list with the component FlatList in the tvOS environment. The problem occurs on a small list of 3 elements, I set the initialScrollIndex equal to the second or last element, the good item is selected. However when I try to go back on a previous item the selection occurs but there is no scroll.

```
<FlatList
  getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
     length: 300,
 offset: 300 * index,
      index,
  })}
  initialScrollIndex={this.props.initialScrollIndex}
  keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
  horizontal={this.props.horizontal}
  scrollEnabled={true}
  extraData={this.state}
  ref={list => (this.myScrollView = list)}
  data={this.finalData}
  removeClippedSubviews={false}
  renderItem={this.props.renderRow}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the properties of the returning object within `getItemLayout` from `length: 300` to `width: 300`. I would think this should be `width` rather than `length` because you are rendering a horizontal FlatList.

```
getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({
  width: 300, //- Here
  offset: 300 * index,
    index,
  }
)}
```